# Creating a Path in multiple steps

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to create a path, then immediately retrieve it and modify it. The problem is that the path gets created and displayed correctly but then I am unable to retrieve it and modify it further.

UPDATE: The problem is that when I call CGContextClosePath in the second function the compiler returns this error:
**: CGContextClosePath: no current point.** 
It basically does not "recognise" the old path and therefore it cannot close it. Any advice would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
//Defined at the very beginning outside the functions
CGMutablePathRef _path;

//First function
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); 

CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), BrushSize);

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  
_path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGContextAddPath (context, _path);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

CGContextStrokePath(context);

drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


//Second function
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapRound
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), BrushSize); //1.0); // Brush size

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

CGPathRef pathFill = CGPathCreateCopy (_path);
CGContextAddPath (context, pathFill);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);

drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path to the context again before you stroke it.

```
CGContextAddPath (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), _path);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It that doesn't work, try creating a copy of the original path and add a new line to that instead of trying to use the original. Use:

```
CGPathCreateCopy
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get it work (please see above the edited question). Cheers